# What is good way to getElementsByClass() with HTTPUnit?

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing

I tried

```
HTMLElement[] focused = response.getElementsWithAttribute("class", "focused");
```

I was hoping it would find

```
<span class="focused">Submit</span>
```

among others, but all I get back is an empty array.

Google has been no help to me.

So. If you were me and you wanted to get an array of HTMLElements by class name, what would you use?

Edit:

The source

```
public class ExampleIT extends TestCase {
    private final String BASE = "http://localhost:8080/preview.htm?";

    @Test
    public void testFocusedArePresent() throws MalformedURLException, SAXException, IOException {
        WebConversation conversation = new WebConversation();
        WebResponse response = conversation.getResponse(BASE + "template=Sample");
        HTMLElement[] focused = response.getElementsWithAttribute("class", "focused");
        assertTrue(focused.length > 0);
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: <version>1.6.2</version>

Comment: Do you have a simple example of the source?  It seems like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsWithAttribute` works for me. Alternatively, you can try iterating over the DOM, looking for an element with a specified class attribute. Here is some sample code:

```
    Document doc = response.getDOM();
    List<Node> result = new ArrayList<Node>();
    NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < list.getLength() ; i++){
        Node n = list.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("class");
        if(n!=null && "focused".equals(n.getNodeValue())){
            result.add(n); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why, but getElementsWithAttribute works as expected with certain elements but not others. It appears that finding an <img> by its class causes no trouble, but <div> and <span> do.